# Diferencia entre string y String en C#?

Tags: c#

Ejemplo (presten atención a las mayusculas y minúsculas):

```
    string s = "Hola mundo!";
    String S = "Hola mundo!";
```

¿Cuál es el uso correcto de cada línea? 
¿Cuáles son las diferencias?

Básicamente quisiera saber si hay diferencias de implementación y en que caso valdría la pena usar car una.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string es un "alias" en C# para System.String. Técnicamente no hay ninguna diferencia. Es similar a usar sólamente int 
en vez de System.Int32. Sin embargo es recomendado utilizar string cada vez que se hace referencia a un objecto.

Ejemplo:

```
string lugar = "mundo";
```

También es recomendado usar String si se necesita referir específicamente a la clase.

Ejemplo:

```
string saludo = String.Format("Hola {0}!", lugar);
```

Generalmente este estilo es el que utiliza Microsoft en sus ejemplos.
Parece que la pregunta es similar a otras, así que intenté elaborar un poco más sobre en qué casos valdría la pena usar una implementación sobre la otra.